# How to arrange a DAG to run some tasks in parallel and then one task when they have completed?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a few tasks that can be run at the same time. When they're finished I need to run a final task. I've tried to do this using task grouping like so:

```
import airflow
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

with airflow.DAG(
        'my_dag',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    ) as dag:

    with TaskGroup(group_id='task_group_1') as tg1:

    
        task1 = MyOperator(
            task_id='task1',
            dag=dag,
        )

        task2 = MyOperator(
            task_id='task2',
            dag=dag,
        )
        
        [task1, task2]    
    
    final_task = MyOtherOperator(
        task_id="final_task",
        dag=dag
    )

    tg1 >> final_task
```

However what happens here is final_task is run multiple times after each task in the task group so:

task1 -> final_task
task2 -> final_task

What I want is for the task group to run in parallel and when it's finished for the the final task to run just once so:

[task1, task2] -> final_task

I thought using task groups would help me accomplish this requirement but it isn't working as expected. Can anyone help? Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the result from the Airflow docs example. It results in task3 being run after both group.task1 and group1.task2. I need it to run just once after both of the grouped tasks are finished.

[image]

LAST EDIT:
It turns out I misunderstood tree view - graph view confirms the grouping operation though I am still getting some other errors for the final task. Thanks for helping me learn more about DAGs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing `[task1, task2]` from the TaskGroup so that it looks like the following:

```py
import airflow
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

with airflow.DAG(
        'my_dag',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    ) as dag:

    with TaskGroup(group_id='task_group_1') as tg1:
        task1 = MyOperator(
            task_id='task1',
            dag=dag,
        )

        task2 = MyOperator(
            task_id='task2',
            dag=dag,
        )
        
    
    final_task = MyOtherOperator(
        task_id="final_task",
        dag=dag
    )

    tg1 >> final_task
```

I don't think you need to return anything from the TaskGroup as you're doing. Just reference the TaskGroup as a dependency.

Here is an example from the apache [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#taskgroups):

```py
with TaskGroup("group1") as group1:
    task1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task1")
    task2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task2")

task3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task3")

group1 >> task3
```

Also, you don't need to use TaskGroups to achieve this functionality. You could simply do this:

```py
import airflow
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup

with airflow.DAG(
        'my_dag',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    ) as dag:

    task1 = MyOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        dag=dag,
    )

    task2 = MyOperator(
        task_id='task2',
        dag=dag,
    )
        
    final_task = MyOtherOperator(
        task_id="final_task",
        dag=dag
    )

    task1 >> final_task
    task2 >> final_task
```

Comment: Interesting - I was using the Astronomer docs which include returning something from the task group https://www.astronomer.io/guides/task-groups/#:~:text=Unlike%20SubDAGs%2C%20Task%20Groups%20are,all%20while%20using%20less%20code!

Comment: Removing the line you suggested still results in the final_task being duplicated for every task in the task group. I'll have to go a bit deeper I think.

Comment: Even the Airflow example duplicates it in the DAG visualization

Comment: I would say that you need to add image to your question because it's not clear what you mean by duplicate.

Comment: I have switched from tree to graph view at lit looks like it has been working all along. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @CClarke Ah ok! now I understand your confusion. The tree view just shows different hierarchy it's not duplications. The tree view was removed in Airflow 2.3 (replaced by Grid view which is more powerful and less confusing)